# Вечные куки в PHP при входе в аккаунт

Tags: php, cookie

Подскажите, (только начал работать с PHP) как и куда записать код с запоминанием вечных куки при входе пользователя, чтобы учётная запись была активна до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмёт кнопку *выйти* или не очистит куки через браузер самостоятельно. Прикрепляю страницу входа

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

$data = $_POST;
if ( isset($data['do_login']) )
{
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
    if ( $user )
    {
        //логин существует
        if ( password_verify($data['password'], $user->password) )
        {
            //если пароль совпадает, то нужно авторизовать пользователя
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">location="index.php";</script>';
        }else
        {
            $errors[] = 'Логин или пароль не совпадают';
        }

    }else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Логин или пароль не совпадают';
    }

    if ( ! empty($errors) )
    {
        //выводим ошибки авторизации
        echo '<div id="errors" style="color:red; text-align:center;">' .array_shift($errors). '</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую Вам воспользоваться супер-глобальной переменной `$_SESSION` и сессиями в целом. Подробнее Вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://komotoz.ru/uroki/php/sessii_v_php.php). Но сессии тоже не вычны, они сбрасываются при очистке файлов `cookie`, ведь сессия основана на этих файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такое решение.

Устанавливаете папку для сессии

Вставьте в начало нужного файла

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600*24*30);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600*24*30);
```

Каждый запуск данного файла эти значения будут переустанавливаться. Сессия будет вечной